# How can we create a folder and file using RandomAccessFile in a single statement?

Tags: java, file, io, directory, randomaccessfile

When we write `RandomAccessFile r =new RandomAccessFile("file.txt","rw");`

how can I create this file in a folder named home on the desktop..
Again it should be a single statement!

Comment: Do you mean you want to open `"desktop/file.txt"` ?

Comment: Create..I wanna create a file along with opening it

Comment: No, it shouldn't be a single statement.  A single statement is not debuggable.

Comment: What??? I did not understand!

Comment: Your question states you want to `create a folder`  How can you create a folder if a file already exists in that folder?

Comment: **create this file in a folder** Read carefully

Answer (score 3):

'RandomAccessFile r =new RandomAccessFile("C:/Users/Siddharth Yadav/Documents/file.txt","rw");'

`RandomAccessFile r =new RandomAccessFile(path_of_file,"rw");`
If file already exists then it is opened else the file is created and then opened